# How detect which column selected in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: javafx, tableview

How to detect, which column(name or id whatever) was selected when user clicked on certain cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable individual cells to be selected, instead of entire rows, call

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

To keep track of which cell(s) are selected, you can do

```
final ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
selectedCells.addListener(new ListChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change change) {
        for (TablePosition pos : selectedCells) {
            System.out.println("Cell selected in row "+pos.getRow()+" and column "+pos.getTableColumn().getText());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `pos.getColumn()` returns an int, so you can't use `.getTitle()` on it, but this code is still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to apply this type of processing, albeit in Kotlin.  I am pretty sure the programming language (Java vs Kotlin) should not matter in this situation.

Unfortunately, the approach suggested above did not work for me (perhas I made a mistake) as I received an error message " 2 type arguments expected for class TablePosition<S : Any!, T : Any!>"

Here is the code I tried:

```
    val listChangeListener = ListChangeListener<TablePosition>()
    {  fun onChanged(c: ListChangeListener<TablePosition>)
        {   println("Selection changed: ")
        }
    }


    this.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    var selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
    selectedCells.addListener(listChangeListener)
```

I have found references elsewhere to this problem - [Why is a JavaFXML TablePosition instance considered as a raw type when type arguments are declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634577/why-is-a-javafxml-tableposition-instance-considered-as-a-raw-type-when-type-argu)

I did find a solution.  I added a mouse click event handler for the tableview, and in the event handler, when it is triggered, I then get the selected indices using

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells()
```

PhilTroy