# Why is a JavaFXML TablePosition instance considered as a raw type when type arguments are declared?

Tags: generics, javafx

The following code is isolated from a fairly complicated accounting application I am developing but the compiler warning is exactly the same as that returned when the application is compiled. Some of the logic required by the application is to ensure that the viewport of a TableView begins with a certain transaction.

```
package tabpane2.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import newdawn.model.TxnObject;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
  @FXML private Button exitBtn;
  @FXML private Button goBtn;
  @FXML private TableView<TxnObject> txnTable;
  @FXML private TableColumn<TxnObject, String> txnDateCol;
  @FXML private TableColumn<TxnObject, String> toFromCol;
  private ObservableList<TxnObject> txnData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 


  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    txnDateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().localtxnDateProperty());
    toFromCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().toFromProperty());
    setTableView();
    txnTable.setItems(txnData);
  }

  private void getTablePosition() { 
    ObservableList<TablePosition> rowvals  = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowvals.size(); i++) {
      TablePosition pos = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(i);
      int row = pos.getRow();
      TxnObject obj = txnTable.getItems().get(row);
      System.out.println("Txn is " + obj.toString());
    }
  }

  private void setTableView(){
    txnData.add(new TxnObject("19000101","001","Fred","B","C","D","0.00","0.00","0.00"));
    txnData.add(new TxnObject("19000102","001","Lars","B","C","D","0.00","0.00","0.00"));
    txnData.add(new TxnObject("19000102","002","Bertil","B","C","D","0.00","0.00","0.00"));
  }

  @FXML private void handleGoBtn() {
    getTablePosition();
  }

  @FXML private void handleExitBtn() {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

The dump returned looks like this:

```
G:\J2EE\TabPane_2\src\tabpane2\view\MainController.java:33: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: TablePosition
    ObservableList<TablePosition> rowvals  = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
  missing type arguments for generic class TablePosition<S,T>
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in class TablePosition
    T extends Object declared in class TablePosition
G:\J2EE\TabPane_2\src\tabpane2\view\MainController.java:35: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: TablePosition
      TablePosition pos = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(i);
  missing type arguments for generic class TablePosition<S,T>
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in class TablePosition
    T extends Object declared in class TablePosition
```

Reading the dump it says that two type arguments are needed by `TablePosition`, ie, S and T. So I tried replacing the `pos` declaration with:

```
TablePosition<TxnObject, TxnObject> pos = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(i);
```

and also tried:

```
TablePosition<TxnObject, String> pos = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(i);
```

But the compilation then returns:

```
G:\J2EE\TabPane_2\src\tabpane2\view\MainController.java:33: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: TablePosition
    ObservableList<TablePosition> rowvals  = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
  missing type arguments for generic class TablePosition<S,T>
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in class TablePosition
    T extends Object declared in class TablePosition
G:\J2EE\TabPane_2\src\tabpane2\view\MainController.java:36: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
      TablePosition<TxnObject, TxnObject> pos = txnTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(i);
  required: TablePosition<TxnObject,TxnObject>
  found:    TablePosition
```

or

```
  required: TablePosition<TxnObject,String>
  found:    TablePosition
```

I don’t understand why the warning is raised even though I am giving `TablePosition` the arguments it asked for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the warning is telling you to replace all `TablePosition` with `TablePosition<TxnObject,String>`. This is equivallent to changing `TableColumn<TxnObject, String>` to `TableColumn`. The type of the `TableColumn` would be undefined in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in—or, if the design is actually intentional, a consequence of—the API signature. If you look at the [`TableViewSelectionModel#getSelectedCells()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html#getSelectedCells()) method you'll find it returns an `ObservableList<TablePosition>`. As you can see, the list declares the *raw type* of `TablePosition` which effectively erases the generic information used with the `TableView`. If it were implemented without raw types, that method would return `ObservableList<TablePosition<S, ?>>` instead.

You're trying to work around this by (implicitly) casting to the generic type, but going from a raw type to a generic type is an unchecked operation, hence the warning(s).

There's a bug report related to this problem: [JDK-8089446](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089446). However, based on the comments, fixing the bug may not be backwards compatible and thus the bug may never be fixed. Note it's not just the above that has this problem, but so does the [`TableViewFocusModel#focusedCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewFocusModel.html#focusedCellProperty) property; there's an enhancement request for this, [JDK-8212737](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212737), but fixing the problem has the same potential issues with backwards compatibility.

Unfortunately there's nothing you can do except suppress the warnings. If this is a problem throughout your application, you could create a utility method to "restore" the generic information:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <S> ObservableList<TablePosition<S, ?>> getSelectedCells(TableView<S> table) {
  return (ObservableList<TablePosition<S, ?>>)
      (ObservableList<?>) table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
}
```

Note that the second type argument of `TablePosition<S, ?>` is a wildcard (i.e. `?`). This is necessary because each table column in the table view is capable of holding a different, arbitrary type.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw I really did not see that one. Your answer and references explain a great deal. Its a real nuisance for me and I will incorporate SupressWarnings. Thanks again.